# Upload IFormFile using Refit in .Net Core 3.1

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc, refit

I am using Refit current stable version in .Net Core 3.1 application and want to call an API from MVC application with IFormFile property in request model. I have added Multipart attribute at endpoint declaration. I don't want to replace IFormFile with anything else as I have used this across entire project.

Any solution for this please?